# Multi select Dropdown list value when select 2 items it repeated selected times in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multi select dropdown for example, when I select 2(1,2) items it consider 4 items(1,1,2,2) like this and my data also inserted based on length (4)

my code :

```
var selectedvalues=[];
$('#ddlpdf > :selected').each(function() { 
         selectedvalues.push($(this).val());         
     });
```

Comment: How are you calling this? I see nothing in the snippet you've provided that would cause this issue. Consider reading: [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you post some more code

Comment: $(this).val(), this might cause the problem. It might consider previously selected values too

Comment: `this` in OP's example seems to reference the *option*, so assuming this is only called once and his selector is correct, it should only be iterating through selected options. Though without some more code, and some HTML, we won't know. I have to believe that this is not OP's code, but rather a "simplified version" of it, considering this code would almost certainly be emptying the array with each call before the `.each` - again, assuming his selector is correct.